# Parametrizations when my curve is a circle (line integral)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I need to evaluate the following integral: $$\int_{\gamma }^{}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}ds$$ Where, $\gamma$ is defined by $\gamma: x^{2}+y^{2}=ax$. I know that this curve represents a circle but I don't know how to rewrite it such that to write the parametrizations.

All I got is $(x-a)^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}$ but know I have that "$2$" in my curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=$**2**$ax$

How to approach this?

Comment: Write $(x-a/2)^2+y^2=a^2/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation of circle: $x^2+y^2=ax\equiv (x-\frac a2)^2+y^2=(\frac a2)^2$
&

substitute parametric equations, $x=\frac a2(1+\cos\theta)$ & $y=\frac{a}{2}\sin\theta$
$$\int_{\gamma}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}ds=\int_0^{2\pi}a\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}\cdot \frac{a}{2}d\theta$$
$$=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right|d\theta$$
$$=2a^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir! So I get $\frac{a^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}dt$ which is different from your result and I don't know what I'm doing wrong because $1+\cos(t)=2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})$ so I would get a new $\sqrt{2}$ to have the same answer as you have in the integral.

Comment: It's weird because if I replace a=2 for example, I get the answer 0 with your answer but with my posted integral result the numerical answer is 8,  $2*a^{2}$.I'll remake it in the morning.Thank you again:)

Answer (score 2):

You approach it by using the fact that$$x^2+y^2=ax\iff\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}4.$$So, a parametrization will be$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,2\pi]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&\theta&\mapsto&\displaystyle\left(\frac a2+\frac a2\cos(\theta),\frac a2\sin(\theta)\right).\end{array}$$